# Inspector: Expected to find at least one React renderer

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion, inspector

I am working on a react-native app and set up my Android App. I am using

```
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.55.3"
```

Genymotion Version 2.12.0
React Native Debugger 0.7.18

I have some styling problems and wanted to solve them. For that I wanted to use the Inspector. Nothing else is enabled. Toggling the inspector works. When I try to inspect an item with clicking on it, I get this error:

[image]

Debugging with React Native Debugger works, if that helps. Inspector works on iOS. Has anybody an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Hi there, have you found a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and it drove me nuts.

The solution to this was to remove a package which was using another package that was causing the issue. In my case, I had to uninstall react-native-root-toast

Found the answer in the last comment in the link below:
https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1032

Search the web and this was the only answer that worked. Hope it helps someone